# php-diff - show "no differences" if 2 files are identical

Tags: php, diff

I'm using [php-diff](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-diff/blob/master/example/example.php) which is an excellent web-based diff tool with very good output when files are different.

The issue I'm having is that when 2 files are identical, there is no output at all.

The code I'm using is as per the example on the link above using the "side by side" output:

```
$a = explode("\n", file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/a.txt'))
$b = explode("\n", file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/b.txt'));
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/Diff/Renderer/Html/SideBySide.php';
$options = [];
$diff = new Diff($a, $b, $options);
$renderer = new Diff_Renderer_Html_SideBySide;
echo $diff->Render($renderer);
```

Assume the contents of `a.txt` and `b.txt` are identical.
If I `var_dump($diff)` it's showing an object which contains contents of both files, and the properties of `class Diff`.

The trouble with this is there's nothing in `$diff` that I can use to determine whether the files are identical because `$diff->Render` only seems to output anything when there are differences.

Does anyone know how it's possible to modify this to include something, even a simple message, such as "no differences between these files".

Comment: Can't you just assign it to a variable and check if the variable is empty? If empty then you echo "no differences between these files" otherwise you echo the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
class SideBySideWithMessage extends Diff_Renderer_Html_SideBySide {
      public function render() {
           $html = parent::render(); 
           if (empty($html)) { 
               return "Files are identical"; //Could do some formatting as well
           }
           return $html;
      }
}



$renderer = new SideBySideWithMessage;
echo $diff->Render($renderer);
```